# Java Sockets - Sending Objects and distributing the object to all clients that are connected

Tags: java, sockets

So here I am, with a 3d game, works great and stuff...

However, I wish to make it multi-player.
I am very new to sockets, so I don't fully understand how to use them, and more specifically, how to send objects from client to server, and then distribute that object to all the other clients.

This is the object that I made that I wish to send:

```
public class Vector3f{

    int x, y, z;

    public Vector3f(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

(It is for the position of the players)
The client class would create a new Socket simply to my local IP, and port 1500 (for example), while the server would create the server socket to port 1500 (obviously).

I would just like to know how I could send across this object to the server (or host), where the server then edits the object to have different values, and then sends it back. E.g:

In the Client class, something like:

```
Vector3f origionalpos = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
System.out.println("x: "+origionalpos.x+" y: "+origionalpos.y+" z: "+origionalpos.z);

ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(origionalpos);
```

Then the Server would receive this, and modify the object, before sending it back, something like this:

```
Vector3f obj = ObjectRecievedFromClient;
obj.x+=10;
obj.y+=10
obj.z+=10
ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
//here I would also like to send to all clients who are connected.
```

Realistically in my game I would not change the position from the server (unless i want to tp them with a command or something), merely redistribute it to the other clients, however I would like to see proof that it has worked first :)

Then finally, in the Client class, it would receive the new Position and assign another object to equal the object received from the server and do something like this:

```
Vector3f newpos = ObjectInputStream.readObject();
System.out.println("x: "+newpos.x+" y: "+newpos.y+" z: "+newpos.z);
```

Any help would be awesome. Remember that this is not yet to put into my game so for now will only be these 3 classes, where the Client class has its own main method, and so does the Server class.

Comment: look into using an ObjectOutputStream or some other way to serialize your objects.  This link has an example of a Chat Client ( http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076864/java-concurrency/building-an-internet-chat-system.html ) modify it to send data objects instead of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, its as simple as:

Client:

```
private Socket socket = null;
private ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
private ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
Vector3f v3f = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
```

and then:

```
socket = new Socket("localHost", port);

System.out.println("Player Position: " + v3f.x+","+v3f.y+","+v3f.z);
outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outStream.writeObject(v3f);

inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
v3f = (Vector3f) inStream.readObject();
System.out.println("New Player Position: " + v3f.x+","+v3f.y+","+v3f.z);
```

Server:

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private Socket socket = null;
private ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
private ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
Vector3f v3f = null;
```

then:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

and finally:

```
while (true) {    
     socket = serverSocket.accept();

     inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     v3f = (Vector3f) inStream.readObject();

     v3f.x += 10;
     v3f.y += 10;
     v3f.z += 10;

     outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     outStream.writeObject(v3f);    
}
```

Oh and dont forget to implement Serializable in the Vector3f class :)